# css media query not working in firefox

Tags: css, media-queries

I am new to CSS media queries and trying to learn it. The following html code show the red background in Firefox whereas it is green in chrome on a 1400 X 1050 resolution. Can someone please tell me what is wrong here

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @media screen and (min-height: 901px) and (max-height: 1050px){
            body{
                font-size: 17px;
                background:green;
            }
        }
        @media screen and (max-height: 900px){
            body{
                font-size: 27px;
                background:red;
            }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    TEST
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `max-height` reffers to the browser height, not the screen height

Comment: You should add max-width instead of max-height

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude  can you suggest me how to fix this so that it behave exactly same in both the browser.

Comment: Nothing wrong in the code, works fine for me

Comment: @atul both browsers will render the same when the viewport is equal height. Probably your firefox have a bookmarks bar that stretch more the height of the browser.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude thanks a lot yes you are correct :)